# Multiple parameters URL redirection to another preety URL

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect via htaccess:
    **test.mydomain.com/articles_main.php?post=POSTTILE&name=&email=**

To:
    **mydomain.com/POSTTILE**

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have struggled with this for a long time, please help.

EDIT:
I have tested many things but what remained commented is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/articles_main.\.php\?post=([^&]*)&name=([^&]*)&email=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles_main\.php\?post=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)&name=&email=$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^articles_main\.php\?post=([A-Za-z0-9]+)&?$ ^/$1/?$ [R=301]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please show us the best try out of your long time struggle...

Comment: Edit the question and post your code there, it is very difficult to read from comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is not correct. Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/articles_main\.php\?post=([^&]+)&name=([^&]*)&email=([^&\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain.com/$1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ articles_main\.php?post=$1name=&email= [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Not working, I also tried this but without success: RewriteRule ^articles_main\.php\?post=([^&]+)&name=([^&]*)&email=([^&]*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Also, I want a redirection to the new domain